# Add prefix to the columns in a slice of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly huge DataFrame (~500 columns and >5000 rows). I want to add a prefix to the first 15 columns. I found a function called `add_prefix()` that can set a prefix to all columns at once. I tried the following:

```py
df[df.columns[range(0,15)]] = df[df.columns[range(0,15)]].add_prefix('f_')
```

with `'f_'` being the prefix I would like to add. Yet, the output doesn't seem to change.

```py
>>>
       mean        std         var  ...         525       526  label
0 -2.546261  17.827072  317.804485  ...   -0.314016 -0.310878    0.0
1 -2.338710  17.915556  320.967136  ...   -0.345603 -0.343088    0.0
2 -2.095051  17.539407  307.630788  ...   -0.323596 -0.324990    0.0
3 -1.685209  18.257797  333.347150  ...   -0.310060 -0.320796    0.0
4 -1.846169  17.240523  297.235618  ...   -0.318660 -0.322732    0.0
```

What I would like to have is:

```py
>>>
     f_mean      f_std       f_var  ...         525       526  label
0 -2.546261  17.827072  317.804485  ...   -0.314016 -0.310878    0.0
1 -2.338710  17.915556  320.967136  ...   -0.345603 -0.343088    0.0
2 -2.095051  17.539407  307.630788  ...   -0.323596 -0.324990    0.0
3 -1.685209  18.257797  333.347150  ...   -0.310060 -0.320796    0.0
4 -1.846169  17.240523  297.235618  ...   -0.318660 -0.322732    0.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `df.iloc[:,0:15] = df.iloc[:,0:15].add_prefix('f_')`

Comment: This one also doesn't seem to work, it just fills the first 15 columns with NaN :D

Comment: Try `df.columns = df.add_prefix('f_').columns[0:15].tolist() + df.columns[15:].tolist()`

Comment: That one works as well, thanks!

Comment: Ah my suggestion fails because you're trying to assign renamed columns to the originally named columns. As there is a mismatch, you get `NaN`, it's best to rename the columns directly

Comment: The weird thing is why it silently fails when using your method

Comment: @EdChum `pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:15].add_prefix('f_'),df.ilic[:,16:]],axis=1)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben yes that would work, not pretty though. Still it's a mystery why it silently fails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot directly assign a prefix as you are currently doing it, given that indices do not support mutable operations. So you would have to reassign all columns again. Here's one way to do it with a list comprehension:

```
df.columns = ['f_' + i if ix < 15 else i for ix, i in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: Cool, you get an upvote for solving my problem, but now I'm kind of curious why it doesn't work my way :D

Comment: Well note that you are trying to modify an index, which does not support mutable operations. So the way to go is to modify all column names

Comment: don't forget to green tick : )

Comment: So ```.add_prefix('f_')``` simply will not work on a subset of columns?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't @ga97dil. Glad this helped!